# three.js r70: issues merging THREE.PlaneBufferGeometries

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use the new (introduced in r70) THREE.BufferGeometry.merge functionality on buffer geometries created with THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry but I'm getting a error during the subsequent render call (the merging itself is working without errors).

- error message in Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined`
- error message in Firefox: `TypeError: this.attributes.position is undefined`
- affected line of code: line 8679 in non minified r70 build: `var positions = this.attributes.position.array;` in buffer geometry's computeBoundingSphere

I was able to reduce the test case to a simple cube model (trying to merge all faces of the cube into a single BufferGeometry):

```
var camera, geometry, matrix, mesh, nx, ny, nz, px, py, pz, renderer, scene;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x888888);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 70;
camera.position.x = 70;
camera.position.y = 70;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

px = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50);
px.applyMatrix(matrix.makeRotationY(Math.PI / 2));
px.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(25, 0, 0));

nx = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50);
nx.applyMatrix(matrix.makeRotationY(-Math.PI / 2));
nx.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(-25, 0, 0));

py = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50);
py.applyMatrix(matrix.makeRotationX(-Math.PI / 2));
py.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(0, 25, 0));

ny = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50);
ny.applyMatrix(matrix.makeRotationX(Math.PI / 2));
ny.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(0, -25, 0));

pz = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50);
pz.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(0, 0, 25));

nz = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(50, 50);
nz.applyMatrix(matrix.makeRotationY(Math.PI));
nz.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(0, 0, -25));

geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.merge(px);
geometry.merge(nx);
geometry.merge(py);
geometry.merge(ny);
geometry.merge(pz);
geometry.merge(nz);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000}));
scene.add(mesh);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Here is a jsfiddle of a:

- broken scene using PlaneBufferGeometry: http://jsfiddle.net/chrmoritz/gpt2xjmb/
- working scene using normal PlaneGeometry: http://jsfiddle.net/chrmoritz/gpt2xjmb/1/

From my understanding THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry should have taken care of setting the BufferGeometry's position attribute with the vertex positions.
Did I do something completly wrong or is this a bug in threejs r70?

Comment: 1. This appears to be a bug in `BufferGeometry.merge()`. Step through with a debugger to confirm. If you agree, you can file a [bug report](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) on the three.js site. 2. http://jsfiddle.net/gpt2xjmb/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var bg = new BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
```

at the end to get your merged BufferGeometry. I have the same problem in my projects and need that ugly workaround because of that message. Is there any bug report or fix yet?

Comment: okay I tried another method: For you
`px.merge(nx);`
should work but when adding another BufferedGeometry it's not working for me :/

Comment: The issues with `BufferGeometry.merge()` which are causing the issues in my question are: 1. `BufferGeometry.merge()` does not take care of resizing the buffers for you. Instead of just using `geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();` you have to take care that all buffer attributes have the correct length of the expected result. 2. `BufferGeometry.merge()` does not support indexed geometries yet (this is only documented in a commit massage). But adding indexed geometries should be quite easy.

Comment: perhaps you can use DynamicBufferGeometry:

https://github.com/makc/three.js.fork/blob/1dfdd035d8f8fc8c23dacb0e34e70b64f103d9e3/examples/js/DynamicBufferGeometry.js

Answer (score 0):

The code at the end of this github issue should work.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6188

Why it hasn't been pulled I don't know.

Update: I just noticed you were the author