# Using addWheel with compound shapes using physijs

Tags: physijs

Is it possible to add a compound shape when using Physijs's **addWheel** function (in conjunction with **Vehicle**), as you cannot use `wheelparent.geometry` which does not include the children's geometry? The geometries of the children use indexed buffer geometries, and I tried using merge to no avail ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870492/three-js-r70-issues-merging-three-planebuffergeometries) question refers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's a no, it cannot be done. What I did was create my own function to merge all the vertices, correctly indexed, then uses the new geometry to create a new wheel shape.